# How to maintain a VueJS app and how to update it on live server?

Tags: angularjs, vue.js

I have a general question to which I can not find an answer. 
I am new to Javascript apps and frameworks. Let's say that you have a website that is live and running, then when you need to fix bugs or make improvements  you can connect to FTP get the files you need to change and upload them back. 
What about VueJs framework, Angularjs etc., if it must be "built" (compiled) before you can use it on a live server (ex. Apache), how do you maintain such project?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of going about this is to simply `SCP` your build directory to your server. While this is better than `FTP`, it is far from a good solution.

The 'correct' way of going about this would be to use something like [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) to automate the build process - something like when you push to the `master` branch on your repository, you want Travis to automatically pull the changes to the server and build it. This is much better than manual deployment simply because you're now relying on tools such as `Git` for version history, and `Travis` which lets you do an arbitrary number of things on each build. This could include linting, running the build against a test suite to make sure no bugs accidentally make it onto your server, and minifying assets.

There are several alternatives as well, such as [BitBucket Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) and [GitLab CI](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) that might be more convenient for you depending on where your repository is hosted. You could also take a look at [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/).

Comment: Thank you @Prajjwal 
I will take a look at Travis CI.

Answer (score 1):

You have some way to 'build' project like that.

First you never access and update the file with FTP. You have and use git/svn to have versionning of your project. You build and run test on every changes, and you push the result to the repository.

When the push is done, you will have some 'hook' that will be trigger (maybe travis or jenkins). With that, on another server you will run all tests inside the project in an environment which will be the same as the production server. If everything is good, you will deploy the full project on the production server.

To deploy it, the best way is to use your versionning command (git clone the first time, then git pull). If you do it this way, the website may be offline during few seconds. The good thing to do is to build the project inside another folder (or container), build it and then just change the internet redirection

Comment: thank you.  So you say that there is a way to git pull directly from live server ?

Comment: you connect to your server, install git on it like you would do on your computer. Then you call `git clone / git pull`. This will get your project or update it. But if you are with angular or another framework you will need to call your `npm start` method to start the project